# How to access Flask API routes in Docker without specifying port numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, nginx, flask

I have a Flask API with two routes, /callapi1 and /callapi2, which I am deploying using Docker. To scale up the server and handle multiple requests concurrently, I'm using the command docker-compose up -d --build --scale app=2. The Flask API server is being served by Gunicorn.

When running the Docker instances, the server instances are assigned random port numbers, making it difficult to access the APIs without knowing the specific port.

For instance, currently, I can access the APIs like this:
response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:54471/callapi1", json=img_data)
response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:54472/callapi1", json=img_data)

I would like to configure Docker and Nginx so that I can access the APIs without specifying port numbers, like this:
http://localhost/callapi1
http://localhost/callapi2

My Docker Compose file looks like this:

```
version: '4'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: app
    ports:
      - "5000"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

And the nginx.conf file is as follows:

```
    events {
    worker_connections 1000;
}

http { 
    upstream flask_app {
        server app:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:5000;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I configure Docker and Nginx to achieve the desired behavior, allowing me to access the APIs without specifying the port numbers explicitly?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing it.

The DNS for `app` will resolve to the internal IP addresses of the containers, and nginx will round-robin requests across them.

However, you *must* set the scale at start-up as nginx will only ever perform that DNS lookup *once* unless you're paying for Nginx plus/premium/whatevertheycallit. If you change the scale, or the containers restart with new IPs, you'll need to restart the Nginx container to pick up then changes.

Also, IIRC you don't even need a `ports` config section unless you want those ports exposed externally.

All that said, if you're looking to scale services out and/or have more intelligent service location/internal load balancing then you should look at getting into Kubernetes.